# I am using c++ output operators "std::cout <<" how do i get an overloaded function I have written to read the current std::setprecision

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

i have written code to take time_t and produce a date

```
namespace std {
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const time_t* _rawtime)
{
    struct tm timeinfo;

#ifdef WIN32
    localtime_s(&timeinfo, _rawtime);
#else
    timeinfo = *(localtime(*_rawtime));
#endif
    out << timeinfo.tm_year + 1900 << "-" << timeinfo.tm_mon + 1 << "-" << timeinfo.tm_mday;
    return out;
    }
}
```

main code follows

```
    time_t dummy = 123456789;
    std::cout << &dummy << std::endl;   // 1973-11-30`
```

i would like to allow the operator overload to act differently if it encountered say

```
std::cout << std::setprecision(4) << &dummy << std::endl;   // say only output 1973
```

vs

```
std::cout << std::setprecision(7) << &dummy << std::endl;   // say only output 1973-11
```

My question is one of how do i get the overloaded function to read its environment to see what std::setprecision() is currently set?

This should be easy but I have not managed to find it.

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: usually this is done by first formatting the output with a seperate function. It also confirms more with the "no surprises" principle. Nobody expects std::setprecission to affect date/time output. So us something like `std::cout << format_date("%YY", dummy) << "\n";` it is also what the C++20 formatting provides.

Comment: If you still want to write an odd operator, the stream's precision is available as [`out.precision()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/precision).

Comment: Pepijn thank you - I will take your advice on using a function eg format_date.  It is cleaner - it does however create 2 questions - (1) whenever a remapping occurs eg dummy above - it was an extended integer it now becomes yyyy/mm/dd.  The invocation might happen via a "friend" statement.  Does this not then break the non surprises rule? and (2) given that I am using a stream device does not using functions break the stream paradigm? thanks again for your comment rgds Bruce

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`precision()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/precision) member function of the stream. The following example prints a substring for simplicity instead:

```
struct MyType
{
    std::string m_value;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, MyType const& val)
{
    std::cout.write(val.m_value.c_str(), std::min<size_t>(val.m_value.size(), std::max<decltype(s.precision())>(s.precision(), 0)));
    return s;
}


int main()
{
    std::cout << std::setprecision(5) << MyType{ "hello world" } << '\n'; // output: hello
}
```

Note though that it may be more easier to understand, if you introduce a function similar to [`std::quoted`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/quoted) instead, since you using the precision is usually not used for a purpose like this.

```
namespace impl
{
class MyTypeSubstringPrintWrapper
{
    MyType const& m_value;
    size_t m_count;
public:
    MyTypeSubstringPrintWrapper(MyType const& value, size_t count)
        : m_value(value),
        m_count(count)
    {}

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, MyTypeSubstringPrintWrapper const& val)
    {
        auto const& str = val.m_value.m_value;
        std::cout.write(str.c_str(), std::min<size_t>(str.size(), val.m_count));
        return s;
    }
};
} // namespace impl

impl::MyTypeSubstringPrintWrapper LengthLimited(MyType const& value, size_t count)
{
    return { value, count };
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << LengthLimited(MyType{ "hello world" }, 5) << '\n'; // output: hello
}
```

Comment: thanks for the education - I have taken to heart your comment "precision is usually not used for a purpose like this" and used a function